# Dynamically sum the values of labels once they all have values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, aspx-user-control

I have a series of `asp Radiobuttons` which are populating the values of labels fine, but now using a jQuery check, if all of the labels have values then I want to dynamically sum the values.
What code/function would achieve this, using the `clsTxtToCalculate` class or referencing the label values?

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblScore1" CssClass="center clsTxtToCalculate" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblScore2" CssClass="center clsTxtToCalculate" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblScore3" CssClass="center clsTxtToCalculate" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblScore4" CssClass="center clsTxtToCalculate" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$(".clsTxtToCalculate").each(...)`? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your radio change event (I'm guessing you have one of these to populate the labels), you could do something like this after you have populated the label text:

```js
var labels = $('.clsTxtToCalculate'),
    labelsWithText = labels.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() != '';
    });

if (labels.length == labelsWithText.length) {
  // do calculation here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over labels and sum up values:

```js
function notify() {
  var labels = $(".clsTxtToCalculate");
  var total = 0; 
  $.each(labels, function(index,lbl){
    total += parseInt($(lbl).text());
  });
  alert(total)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Label ID="lblScore1" class="center clsTxtToCalculate">10</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <Label ID="lblScore2" class="center clsTxtToCalculate">20</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <Label ID="lblScore3" class="center clsTxtToCalculate">30</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <Label ID="lblScore4" class="center clsTxtToCalculate">40</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="notify()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: thank you but is there a way to check dynamically if all labels have values and the sum is done dynamically once all labels have values?

Comment: What event are you talking about? Adding new `td`?